# How did Duryodhana reach heaven despite harassing Draupadi and trying to kill Pandavas in wax palace?

Tags: mahabharata, bhagavad-gita, dharma

It says in  this QA:

[Where did Duryodhana and Pandavas go after their death](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/946/where-did-duryodhana-and-the-pandavas-go-after-their-death)

that Duryodhana got heaven because in BG Krishna said those who die bravely get heaven. So, is this like Abrahamic religions where Muslims get heaven if they die while fighting jihad, even if they have done other crimes? Duryodhana and his brothers harassed Draupadi and tried to kill Pandavas. Doesn't those crimes count? Is dying in battle that big of a deal so as to ignore all other sins and give them heaven as per Hinduism? How is it a proper portrayal of dharma? Does dharma forgive all sins like Abrahamic religions, if you die in battle for a selfish cause?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Duryodhana attained heaven by dying in battle.

> Om! Having bowed down into Narayana, and to Nara, the foremost of men,
> as also to the goddess Sarasvati, should the word "Jaya" be uttered.
>
> Janamejaya said, "Having attained to Heaven, what regions were
> respectively attained by my grandsires of old, viz., the Pandavas and
> the sons of Dhritarashtra? I desire to hear this. I think that thou
> art conversant with everything, having been taught by the great Rishi
> Vyasa of wonderful feats.
>
> Vaishampayana said, "Listen now to what thy grandsires, Yudhishthira
> and others, did after having attained to Heaven, that place of the
> deities. Arrived at Heaven, king Yudhishthira the just, beheld
> Duryodhana endued with prosperity and seated on an excellent seat. He
> blazed with effulgence like the sun and wore all those signs of glory
> which belong to heroes. And he was in the company of many deities of
> blazing effulgence and of Sadhyas of righteous deeds. Yudhishthira,
> beholding Duryodhana and his prosperity, became suddenly filled with
> rage and turned back from the sight.
>
> "He loudly addressed his companions, saying, ‘I do not desire to share
> regions of felicity with Duryodhana who was stained by cupidity and
> possessed of little foresight. It was for him that friends, and
> kinsmen, over the whole Earth were slaughtered by us whom he had
> afflicted greatly in the deep forest. It was for him that the virtuous
> princess of Pancala, Draupadi of faultless features, our wife, was
> dragged into the midst of the assembly before all our seniors. Ye
> gods, I have no desire to even behold Suyodhana. I wish to go there
> where my brothers are.’
>
> "Narada, smiling, told him, ‘It should not be so, O king of kings.
> While residing in Heaven, all enmities cease. O mighty-armed
> Yudhishthira, do not say so about king Duryodhana. Hear my words.
> **Here is king Duryodhana. He is worshipped with the gods by those righteous
> men and those foremost of kings who are now denizens of Heaven. By
> causing his body to be poured as a libation on the fire of battle, he
> has obtained the end that consists in attainment of the region for
> heroes. You and your brothers, who were veritable gods on Earth, were
> always persecuted by this one. Yet through his observance of Kshatriya
> practices he has attained to this region. This lord of Earth was not
> terrified in a situation fraught with terror.**
>
> "‘O son, thou shouldst not bear in mind the woes inflicted on thee on
> account of the match at dice. It behoveth thee not to remember the
> afflictions of Draupadi. It behoveth thee not to remember the other
> woes which were yours in consequence of the acts of your kinsmen,—the
> woes, viz., that were due to battle or to other situations. Do thou
> meet Duryodhana now according to the ordinances of polite intercourse.
> This is Heaven, O lord of men. There can be no enmities here.’
>
> "Though thus addressed by Narada, the Kuru king Yudhishthira, endued
> with great intelligence, enquired about his brothers and said, ‘If
> these eternal regions reserved for heroes be Duryodhana’s, that
> unrighteous and sinful wight, that man who was the destroyer of
> friends and of the whole world, that man for whose sake the entire
> Earth was devastated with all her horses and elephants and human
> beings, that wight for whose sake we were burnt with wrath in thinking
> of how best we might remedy our wrongs, I desire to see what regions
> have been attained by those high-souled heroes, my brothers of high
> vows, steady achievers of promises, truthful in speech, and
> distinguished for courage. The high-souled Karna, the son of Kunti,
> incapable of being baffled in battle, Dhrishtadyumna, Satyaki, the
> sons of Dhrishtadyumna and those other Kshatriyas who met with death
> in the observance of Kshatriya practices, where are those lords of
> Earth, O Brahmana? I do not see them here, O Narada. I desire to see,
> O Narada, Virata and Drupada and the other great Kshatriyas headed by
> Dhrishtaketu, as also Shikhandi, the Pancala prince, the sons of
> Draupadi, and Abhimanyu, irresistible in battle.’

**Mahabharata Svargarohanika Parva, Section I**

This is not the end of the story. Duryodhana would also have to endure hell after staying in heaven for all the bad things he has done. Duryodhan first stays in heaven and then hell because his sinful acts are many.

> Vaishampayana said, "King Yudhishthira the just, the son of Pritha,
> had not stayed there for more than a moment when, O thou of Kuru’s
> race, all the gods with Indra at their head came to that spot. The
> deity of Righteousness in his embodied form also came to that place
> where the Kuru king was, for seeing that monarch. Upon the advent of
> those deities of resplendent bodies and sanctified and noble deeds,
> the darkness that had overwhelmed that region immediately disappeared.
> The torments undergone by beings of sinful deeds were no longer seen.
> The river Vaitarani, the thorny Salmali, the iron jars, and the
> boulders of rock, so terrible to behold, also vanished from sight. The
> diverse repulsive corpses also, which the Kuru king had seen,
> disappeared at the same time. Then a breeze, delicious and fraught
> with pleasant perfumes, perfectly pure and delightfully cool, O
> Bharata, began to blow on that spot in consequence of the presence of
> the gods. The Maruts, with Indra, the Vasus with the twin Ashvinis,
> the Sadhyas, the Rudras, the Adityas, and the other denizens of
> Heaven, as also the Siddhas and the great Rishis, all came there where
> Dharma’s royal son of great energy was.
>
> "Then Shakra, the lord of the deities, endued with blazing prosperity,
> addressed Yudhishthira and comforting him, said, ‘O Yudhishthira of
> mighty arms, come, come, O chief of men. These illusions have ended, O
> puissant one. Success has been attained by thee, O mighty-armed one,
> and eternal regions (of felicity) have become thine. Thou shouldst not
> yield to wrath. **Listen to these words of mine. Hell, O son, should
> without doubt be beheld by every king. Of both good and bad there is
> abundance, O chief of men. He who enjoys first the fruits of his good
> acts must afterwards endure Hell. He, on the other hand, who first
> endures Hell, must afterwards enjoy Heaven. He whose sinful acts are
> many enjoys Heaven first.** It is for this, O king, that desirous of
> doing thee good, I caused thee to be sent for having a view of Hell.
> Thou hadst, by a pretence, deceived Drona in the matter of his son.
> Thou hast, in consequence thereof, been shown Hell by an act of
> deception. After the manner of thyself, Bhima and Arjuna, and
> Draupadi, have all been shown the place of sinners by an act of
> deception. Come, O chief of men, all of them have been cleansed of
> their sins. All those kings who had aided thee and who have been slain
> in battle, have all attained to Heaven. Come and behold them, O
> foremost one of Bharata’s race.

**Mahabharata Svargarohanika Parva Section III**

One should remember that stays in heaven and hell are temporary in Sanatan Dharma and can't be compared to the eternal heaven and the eternal hell of Abrahamic faiths.